# React Functional Component Render twice after navigate to that Component, But when trying to refresh, Rendered only once

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

When I go to one functional component using react-router, it renders twice.
However, when I refresh the page of that component, it only renders once.

For the test, created empty functional component like that:

```
import React from 'react'

const TestFunctional: React.FC<any> = () => {
  console.log('Test===>>>') // console log twice when navigate to this component
  return <></>
}

export default TestFunctional
```

Here is Router in `App.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, useLocation, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import TestFunctional from 'views/Test'

const AnimatedSwitch = withRouter(({ location }) => (    
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={StartPage} />
     <Route exact path="/test" component={TestFunctional} />
  </Switch>
))

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Web3ReactManager>
        <AnimatedSwitch />
      </Web3ReactManager>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I did not use `React.StrictMode` in `index.tsx`.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
          <Web3ProviderNetwork getLibrary={getLibrary}>
            <App />
          </Web3ProviderNetwork>
        </Web3ReactProvider>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

So it is some weird.
When I refresh this page, `console.log('Test===>>>')` show only once.
What is a mistake and how to fix the double render problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why is that a problem? You should design/write your components assuming that it could re-render at anytime. React is even working on [a new rendering mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html) where your component might be rendered multiple times before it actually gets "rendered in DOM".

As for why it actually renders twice? Not sure, might just be a quick of ReactDOM. As a side note, the [documentation for `component`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) does have this warning for `Route` though:

> When you use component (instead of `render` or `children`, below) the
> router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the
> given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
> results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the `render` or the
> `children` prop (below).

While that shouldn't apply in this case, still handy to know.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Interesting point in my problem is that `Refreshing` && `Direct Open(Url Copy and open to new tab)` is render only once.
Just twice when I come from another page.

Comment: I imagine it's something to do with ReactDOM setting its internal state then perhaps another state change in response to changing the browser's URL using `pushState`. If you replace `component={TestFunctional}` with `render={() => <TestFunctional />}`, React _might_ optimize it by not re-rendering `TestFunctional` because its state/props never change.

Comment: Still same with `<Route exact path="/test" render={() => <TestFunctional />} />`

Comment: Then no idea, just gonna blame ReactDOM internals. In their defense, components should be "re-render resistant" for most purposes, especially when you're using it for these kind of purposes where properties get injected in your component, i.e. `location`.